# Automation to pull data into excel from SQL

Tags: sql, excel, automation

I have a report that I generate on a weekly basis. I have the code written in SQL and I then pull all the data into excel's data model.

I then create pivot tables and dashboards in excel from that particular data.

***The SQL code creates new table of the same name everytime and deletes the older version of the table***. There isn't any way for me to just append the new data as the report is run from the very start and not just on the new data.

I wish to automate this process of refreshing my dashboard from the data I produce in SQL. Is there a way to do so?

Currently I create a new table in SQL, import data into the excel's data model and then recreate the dashboard.

I am not even sure if this is possible. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Do you have SSRS (and the desire to use it)?  Are you already able to run scheduled SQL jobs?  How are your programming skills?  Where do you want the excel sheet to go (email, network share, anywhere is fine)?

Comment: I do not have SSRS currently but Idm using it. I currently do not run scheduled SQL jobs. I am good at programming and the excel sheet is supposed to stay on my local drive!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!

After some digging, I was able to find a feature that Excel's data model supports.
Instead of making a connection directly to a SQL Server Table, you can create a connection by writing a SQL Query.

This way, even if you delete the table for updating it, as far as the name remains the same, Excel's data model would be able to pull data from the table just by you hitting refresh!